# Stretching/compressing images in libgdx

Tags: java, image, libgdx

I've been trying to makes my images scale with resolution but I can't find an easy way of compressing them to a set width and height.

Comment: hi, i was wandering if the answer provided was helpful, if yes , please close it by putting it as resolved, if no, leave a comment so we could help you more, good luck

Comment: It was thank you. I had no idea you could change the spirites size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i use :

```
public static float xTrans(float x)
{
    return x*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SCREEN_WIDTH;
}

public static float yTrans(float y)
{
    return y*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SCREEN_HEIGHT;
}
```

`Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` : is the current screen height of the device

`Gdx.graphics.getwidth()`  : is the current screen width of the device

**SCREEN_WIDTH** is the width screen reference : I put it to (480)

**SCREEN_HEIGHT** is the height screen reference : I put it to (320)

> example of use

```
yourSprite.setSize(xTrans(20),yTrans(15));
```

also you could put diferent size of the same image resource  and load them depending on the size resolution of your screen

hope that was helpfull

good luck

Comment: Just checking is Y the position or the current size?
Also I can't find the method "setSize" under the Texture class

Comment: You could use it for both, to adjust the size according to screen resolution, or to put an object in the same position whereever the  resolution of the screen

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is this the best/easiest way to scale objects for different resolutions? As i am trying to get my game to scale for different mobile screen sizes.